# Partial Fractions

Tags: inverse-problem

Attached is image with solution and my attempt. 
I am trying to calculate the coefficients for partial fractions expansion of the following:

$$ H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ \frac{1}{3} e^{-j2\omega} }{(1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega})(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega}) }$$ 
and I don't get the same answer. Please help[image: ![Solution]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTcAu.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi! You could add a few simple Latex lines into your question to make it better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the solution given in your textbook is wrong but probably It's due to a typo in the system definition which is given as

$$ H_1(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ \frac{1}{3} e^{-j2\omega} }{(1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega})(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega}) }$$

but which should be instead:
$$ H_2(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ \frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega} }{(1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega})(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega}) }$$

The partial fraction expansion for the second system is :

$$ H_2(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ \frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega} }{(1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega})(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega}) } = \frac{ -2 }{1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega}} + \frac{ 2}{1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega} }$$

which is the solution offered in the textbook.

Note that if you wanted to get the PFE of the first system, the result would be:

$$ H_1(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ \frac{1}{3} e^{-j2\omega} }{(1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega})(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega}) } = 2 + \frac{ -6 }{1-\frac{1}{3} e^{-j\omega}} + \frac{ 4}{1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-j\omega} }$$

Note that in this first system (that you tried to solve) the order of numerator is equal to the order of denominator, and a simple long division is required to get it into the form that you have used to solve the coefficients $A$ and $B$.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/56390/25003

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. Let me show the full answer in the solution. The numerator term (1/3) e^(-j2w) is found by dividing y(w)/x(w). I know that you have stated this above but could you please confirm again whether the solution is as you stated for a problem that contains (1/3) e^(-jw) instead of attached solution above.
[image: Solution]

Comment: please add a comment into my answer instead of a new answer...

Comment: Thanks. You are right the definition is incorrect in the DSP book. Sorry I could't add image in comment section. That's why I posted an answer and commented it to your answer.